# Basic Python: comparing lists

Tags: python, function

This is all I have so far:

```
def anagram(str1, str2):

    print("String 1 : %s" %str1) 
    print("String 2 : %s" %str2)
    s1 = sorted(str1.lower()) 
    s2 = sorted(str2.lower())

    if s1 == s2:
       print("This is an anagram") 
       return True

def test_anagram():

    print( "\n** Testing example anagrams **\n")

    tests = [["dog", "cat"]]

    num_anagrams = 0

    for test in tests:
       answer = anagram(test[0] , test[1])
       print("For inputs " + test[0] + " and " + test[1] + " answer is: ", answer, end ="")
       if answer == test[0]:
          print("This test is correct")
          num_anagrams += 1
```

I don't think this is close to right. I want it to compare the actual result to what the function previously gives out as a result, then output whether the result was the same, being 'correct' or not 'incorrect' then output how many tests worked correctly against the function. I can't get my head around the if statement.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: The statement `str1("String 1 : ")` generates this error. What did you mean to do there?

Comment: Do the first couple of chapters of the official python tutorial: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: You also don't need to put the variable names in your function call, use `anagrams("Cat", "Tac")`

Comment: Looks like you just want to `print` the two strings before sorting them, if so, just change those two lines to `print ("String 1 : ", str1)` and similarly for str2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed your code based on what I thought you wanted to do with some comments on what was changed and why:

```
def anagrams(str1, str2):
    print("String 1 : %s" %str1) #you wanted to print it right this is how you can format the string with variables
    print("String 2 : %s" %str2) #you wanted to print it right this is how you can format the string with variables
    s1 = sorted(str1.lower()) #lower function call to remove the capital letters since it matters
    s2 = sorted(str2.lower()) #lower function call to remove the capital letters since it matters

    if s1 == s2:
        print("This is an anagram") # you don't call a bool value with parameter. You use print functions instead and then return True
        return True #you wanted to return True here right? 



anagrams("Cat", "Tac") # no need to assign variables to match parameter names
```

This prints out:

```
String 1 : Cat
String 2 : Tac
This is an anagram
```

I think you were mistaking on how to print things out with variable assignment to the string, I vaguely remember a language that had that had a similar syntax with what you were doing.

You error is basically trying to call a `str` object like a function. Since you took other programming language, I think you should know what's wrong with that statement

Edited:

```
def anagram(str1, str2):

    print("String 1 : %s" %str1) 
    print("String 2 : %s" %str2)
    s1 = sorted(str1.lower()) 
    s2 = sorted(str2.lower())

    if s1 == s2:
        print("This is an anagram") 
        return True

def test_anagram():

    print( "\n** Testing example anagrams **\n")

    tests = [["dog", "cat"],["tac","cat"],["dog","god"]]

    num_anagrams = 0

    for test in tests:
        answer = anagram(test[0] , test[1])
        print("For inputs " + test[0] + " and " + test[1] + " answer is: " + str(answer))
        if answer:
            print("This test is correct")
            num_anagrams += 1
    print(num_anagrams)

test_anagram()
```

Comment: brilliant! That's cleared it up. One last question if you don't mind. I have to create a function with no arguments that tests whether or not the above function works correctly. I have been given this code:

Comment: I've been asked to  call the ’anagram’ function with different strings to test if it is working correctly.
The function should print out in a human readable format the tests that it is
running and whether it passed or not and should report on the total number of tests passed.

Comment: how are you getting the different strings? are they pre enter into the script like above ? all you need is a for loop and just a counter and check if it returns true or false.

Comment: I think Im supposed to do something that uses any sort of words as tests.

Comment: something like:    tests = [["dog", "cat"]] but about 5 or 6 seperate tests

Comment: Well give it a try and if you run into issues edit your question with what you try and what was wrong. You've programmed before so this isn't anything new to you.

Comment: yeah, this is as far as I came for test in tests:
      #  answer = anagram(test[0] , test[1])
      #  print("For inputs " + test[0] + " and " + test[1] + " answer is: ", answer, end ="")

Comment: You can't in comments, I told you to edit your question since that's the only place to format code on this site.

Comment: close.. `if answer == test[0]:` just replace that with `if answer:` since the anagram function returns a bool. and  then after the `for loop` print out your counter.

Comment: so ' if answer: True ' do I put 'then' or ':' ? To start the if statement

Comment: So in Python, `if variable:` will run if the variable is `true`. In python all objects are `true` unless they are a `None`, `False`, `0`, `''` objects. and since your function is returning `True` if it passes or `None` if it doesn't, and you are storing it in `answer`, `if answer:` will work as intended.

Comment: Ah I see. When I run the program, my answer variable is still outputted as None. Any idea why?

Comment: Because you are testing with `"dog", "cat"` as in you are calling `anagram("dog","cat")` and since  those arent anagram of each other of course they are going to return `None`. if you want a real test replace your list with this `tests = [["dog", "cat"],["tac","cat"],["dog","god"]]`

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but when I want to output the 'answer' variable it outputs 'None' Instead of true or false

Comment: Look at the function we wrote `anagram`, it never returns `False`, only `True`. In python when a function runs it will always return `None` even if you don't specify a return. If it bugs you that much you can write `return False` out side of the `if` statement in `anagram` for the last line for the function. `None` is basically `False` But even more special.

Comment: I think ive figured it out. It recalls the answer for the 1st test ("dog", cat") for each of the other tests which recalls 'None'. So the variable doesnt change with each of the tests. For example with the first test.

Comment: yeah, I took out return True by accident. It works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @GeorgeOrchard If you are satisfy with one of the answers, maybe consider accepting one as the answer ( green check mark ) Have a nice day.

Answer (score 4):

You're treating `str1` and `str2` like functions, when you're really just passing `str` objects, which, according to your error, are not callable (i.e. don't work as functions).

Are you trying to accept input? If so, use `str1 = input("String 1 : ")` and so on.

Otherwise, if you're trying to format output, use this:

```
print("String 1 : {}".format(str1))
```

Comment: I don't think it's inputs because he is passing them in as parameters, but who knows need more details from OP.